# Glassfish server unable to run

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, heap-memory

During working on JSP project, an appear sometime because of memory space:
Java heap space ..

i searched for this error and a solution was founded, which it's :
[Configuring Glassfish](http://spaquet.blogspot.com/2006/07/liferay-glassfish-part-ii-configuring.html)

I did as they explained, but i changeed the value that they set to larger values, in explanation they set XX:MaxPermSize to 256m , but i set it to 1024 !
and another parameter in same page was, as i remember xm512 or something like that , i changed it to 2048.

I restarted netbeans, then Glassfish unable to run!
An error appear at first run , may talk about the space 2048 ! , later, this error appear:

```
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Belal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Search Engine\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\Belal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Search Engine\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1058: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution [How to modify JVM Settings in Glassfish](https://gautirao.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/how-to-modify-jvm-settings-in-glassfish/) .